# Getting current timezone

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, amber-smalltalk

How would I get the current timezone in either Pharo or Amber Smalltalk?

(I’m also curious about how I would go about finding this information myself through inspecting the image somehow or however it’s typically done – huge Smalltalk newbie here.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh! I just learned how the object browser works and found this:

In Pharo:

`DateAndTime localTimeZone. a TimeZone(LT-5:00)`

In Amber:

`Date new asTimeString. '11:55:25 GMT-0500 (EST)'`

Comment: In Amber you can also use `Date today asTimeString`. Or you can use inline JavaScript and use the examples from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript. Inline JavaScript is currently represented in  `<>`.